# Turning ClearType of on a 2nd monitor in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, lcd, cleartype

Is it possible to **turn ClearType off** on certain monitors in Windows 7.

ClearType degrades the crispness on the external LCD connected to my laptop. I tried tweaking it using the ClearType adjustment wizard but still no luck.

For some reason this particular screen looks better **without ClearType switched on**.

**Update:**

- This monitor is not in portrait mode
- I don't want tune the ClearType settings, I want to switch it off completely.

Comment: Is the external monitor in portrait mode? ClearType only helps when it is correctly aligned with your monitor's subpixels.

Comment: Yeah, I had a similar annoyance. ClearType does an exemplary job within its small circle of competence. It's not a flexible engine, at least from the outside.

Comment: see my answer [here](http://superuser.com/a/383454/101850)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible. Better use DVI instead of VGA, if possible.

Comment: Thanks, already running in DVI mode. Still not as crisp as compared to using this monitor on an XP machine where ClearType is switched off.

Answer (score 1):

ClearType Text Tuner is available in the Windows 7 Control Panel. You could adjust ClearType settings for selected monitor only.

Comment: I don't want to adjust it, I need to switch it off.

Comment: I'm in the same boat as you, philipf. Was sad to see no option was available to turn it off for a particular monitor.