# ubuntu mono font on vim across linux and windows have different spacing?

Tags: ubuntu, vim, fonts, gvim

On Windows gVim:

[image]

On Ubuntu gVim (same on Vim):

[image]

Why is the padding across the two operating systems so different? Is this a changeable feature?

Comment: Which way do you want it to look? It looks like in Ubuntu you are using font anti-aliasing while in Windows8 you are using ClearType mode instead...

Comment: I'd follow that lead too: the individual characters (ea= and others)are not drawn the same. Usually that's the sign of font rendering problems.

Comment: is this link the way to go regarding font anti aliasing? Not an area im familiar with.

http://superuser.com/questions/367230/how-to-turn-off-cleartype-and-use-whole-pixel-anti-aliasing-in-windows-7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One difference between Windows and other systems is the default for the `'linespace'` setting, which inserts one pixel line between characters on Windows. See `:help 'linespace'`.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the answer given by Ingo, note that starting from [Patch 7.4.393](https://code.google.com/p/vim/source/detail?r=1bff71d202621d97acc4ef21ce9f47b78f68bda3) Vim on Windows let's you tweak the font rendering by setting the `'renderoptions'`